# Лагает(не изменяется/не отвечает) в конфиге nginx.conf один из location. Windows 7 nginx 1.17.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, asp.net-core

Доброго времени суток.

Я хочу проксировать через Nginx запрос http://localhost:3000/app на http://localhost:2000/app

Делаю так(nginx.conf)
...

```
...
location / {  
    proxy_pass http://localhost:2000;
}
location /app {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:2000;
            satisfy any;
            auth_request /auth;
}
...
```

Запрос http://localhost:3000/app приводит к редирект на http://localhost:3000
Запрос http://localhost:3000/app/ завершается как я хочу. Но мне нужно без слеша.
Равно ставил у location, не помогает.

---

### Простыня дополнительной информации

**Сутуация**

На Nginx(:3000) приходит запрос вида http://localhost:3000/app

**Как должно работать**

1.Происходит запрос (Nginx) localhost:3000/app

2.С помощью модуля auth_request Nginx проверяет, есть ли доступ или нет.

3.Если доступа нет(auth сервер на :2500 возвращает 401), то возвращает 401. Иначе обращается к :2000(Node.js) и отдает контент по Uri localhost:2000/app

Все запросы, которые не /app и не начинаются на /api уходят на localhost:2000 без проверки

**Реальность**

При запросе http://localhost:3000/app происходит редирект 301 на http://localhost:3000 и приходит ответ с http://localhost:2000

http://localhost:3000/app/ выполняет то, что нужно(хотя стоит знак равно, тобишь полное соответствие)

**Вопрос**

Как мне реализовать то, что я хочу? Чего я не понимаю тут? Суть в том, что так работало, но внезапно...Перестало.

По отдельности все работает(все запросы). Через nginx нет.

**Данные**

ОС - Windows 7 SP1 x32

1. Node.js -v 10.16.0 (localhost:2000) - отдает страницу регистрации(/sign-in) и приложение(/app)
2. Nginx   -v 1.17.2  (localhost:3000) - по сути роутит запросы/ управляет доступом
3. ASP.NET Core 2.2 Kestrel (localhost:2500) - auth сервер и api

nginx.conf

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http 
{
    server 
    {
        listen       3000;

        location / {  
            proxy_pass http://localhost:2000;
        }
        #location = /sign-in {  
        #   proxy_pass http://localhost:2000;
        #}
        location = /app {
            satisfy any;
            auth_request /auth;

            proxy_pass http://localhost:2000/app;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:2500;
        }
        location =  /auth {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:2500;
            proxy_pass_request_body off;
            proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
            proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        }   
    }
}
```

server.js

```
    const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
var https = require('https');
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
var request = require('request')
const authServer = "http://localhost:2500";
const app = express();


var ssl = require('ssl-root-cas/latest');

ssl.inject();

https.globalAgent.options.ca = ssl.create();

const port = 2000;
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/build')));




// создаем парсер для данных application/x-www-form-urlencoded
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});
app.get('/sign-in',(req,res) => {

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"/build","landing.html"));
    console.log("/sign-in");
});

app.get('/app',(req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"/build","app_main.html"));      
    console.log("/app");
});

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    console.log("/");
    return res.send("OK /");
});


app.listen(port,() => console.log("Server start"));
```

**Update 1:**

Ответ 302 от auth сервера происходил по моей вине. Поправив это, осталась та же проблема(просто если не auth возвращается 401, а не 500 как раньше)

**Update 2:**

Очевидно решение кроется около вот этой статьи(т.е документации) к которой я обращаюсь с самого начала появления этой проблемы. Руководствуясь ей, не понимаю, что я делаю не так http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Даже вот о моей ситуации есть

[image: Описание почти моей ситуации(но мне нужен только /app без /app/]

**Update 3:**

Авторизация(Login)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.17.2
Date: Tue, 23 Jul 2019 17:46:30 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: idsrv.session=48e5d3d975ccf180585ffe3c91fb1b68; path=/
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8ELoSoNWqjJOgDxKtEwem1LEM0p7aar
3RcD6H87Jl-fNu-oSNxx_U0ZUbGx-MUOSGgaeOzt48Xq69ADVzTQDNiTjYvddytn3ndA53u4G890Jio9
GmY_7alZlYORb9sE9JD4zVyRNwXqT3xOIgLhk-Q6m0QbOubtz0CowANnyWDmmX7oINloLoQpYXu-vcyn
NYpYS9EMKNYNsic1tX2g7HL-2Avap8mBQm7v3UlIV83mxZ_zC4db4iJQ5CCAlprXTYNSQnkcTydAk4zX
IrGD4y3A2u96kA6SDsFbCH12xHwII6wavhKyd-myCsyd_tsDARD0RY8A4MRxw39odofCmPzW1BIFaWex
fZ8fI42bJVHsVqaD-gTmTxrmfNHO3wSVa0FvRcAWjf435cNQp3Wly2pIJ4PT5b-F-FBCKbrUGAeiFbD4
qs1CbAf81MtExIqq1ObWRh9qENTgObxNWF-*eei2EIzjEROu746nVyxngGUSgZxFCCWtzAO6nlLjAt0*
1ZccCSfXgZMCX4cqeK4VacryncbndwypKurbld_FxEcbtLb0-uPkX04WNnJ-Kh-TTaQ; expires=Thu
, 22 Aug 2019 17:46:30 GMT; path=/; httponly
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcQXJ0ZW1cRG9jdW1lbnRzXF9Qcm9qZWN0c1xCaW9JbnY
uQmFja2VuZC5BdXRoXEJpb0ludi5CYWNrZW5kLkF1dGhcYXBpXEFjY291bnRcTG9naW5BY3Rpb25BcmE
=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Запрос на /auth по сути проверка авторизован ли(есть ли куки). Если есть - отдаем Ok и nginx пускает, иначе отдает 401 и не пускает.

Понимаю, что скорее всего обычно передается логин пароль.

Comment: Долго пытался понять, все запутанно. Можете по-другому переформулировать: как должно работать? Зачем конфиг ноды.

Comment: @TotalPusher попробовал описать понятнее. Так лучше? Конфиг ноды тут т.к один из серверов - это сервак на Node. Тут 3 сервера Nginx(роутинг по сути), ASP.NET Core (авторизация и api), Node.js(отдает контент необходимый для формирования страниц)

Comment: какой тип авторизации? `curl -i {параметры авторизации} http://localhost:2500/auth` что возвращает? `При запросе http://localhost:3000/app происходит редирект 301 на http://localhost:3000 и приходит ответ с http://localhost:2000 OK /(это корректно)` - не понятно, что тут корректного? Все высказывание? Либо вы не понимаете как работает `auth_request`, либо я не понимаю, почему 301 редирект - это корректно.

Comment: @TotalPusher  1. IdentityServer. Судя по всему вам нужен был не /auth(в моем случае он лишь проверяет есть ли куки и активны ли они), а сам метод авторизации. Возможно это не корректно(используется по-другому обычно), но реализует то, что нужно.(результат добавил в ответ Update 3).  Корректно только последнее действие( при запросе http://localhost:2000 отвечает Ок). Убрал эти слова из вопроса, ибо путает. 
Auth_request: мы передаем данные. Если все ок и возвращается 200, то пускаем. Если нет и возвращается 401, то не пускаем. В данном случае это не корректно, поправлю, но работает.

Comment: @TotalPusher если интересно, посмотрите ответ. Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть в тол, что Nginx(по моим разумениям) залагал на location /app.

До этого я прописывал внутри location /app `error_page 401 404 500 = /;`  или/и  `error_page 401 404 500 = @access_denied` и после этого Nginx начал постоянно редиректить просто так на / без видимых причин. Изменений конфига не помогли, как и сборка занова(без конфигурации заново, просто nmake).

Возможно это из-за того, что запускаю на Windows.

**Решение:**

Пока что изменил название с /app на /app_index и все завелось с пол пинка.

**UPDATE 1.**

Возможно все проще. До этого на localhost:3000/app сидел Node.js(во время разработки), а после я пересадил на localhost:3000 Nginx сервер.

В итоге во время некоторых(не знаю каких) манипуляций в кеше сохранился Node.js -ий вариант /app. Из-за этого браузер выдавал 301, а не сервер. Из-за того, что в кеше лежало другое.